# Could i use react-virtualized for rendering and modifying large tabular data?

Tags: reactjs, view, grid, tabular, react-virtualized

I would like to build a service that can manage large dataset by grid view. It's similar to Excel or Google's Spreadsheet. The service can render and modify directly on the grid view.

I would like to use react or some latest technology to develop the front-end. I found a react component named react-virtualized.

I still wonder that can it implement modification functionality on it.

Could you explain me more about how it work or under the hood ? Actually i need some idea to propose the solution like this.

Answer (score 2):

> Could i use react-virtualized for rendering and modifying large tabular data?

Yes.

Sounds like you're looking to build something like [this](https://bvaughn.github.io/forward-js-2017/#/29/1). It is built with react-virtualized and the source code for it can be found [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/forward-js-2017/blob/master/src/Components/Spreadsheet.js).

> Could you explain me more about how it work or under the hood ? Actually i need some idea to propose the solution like this.

This question is a bit too vague for Stack Overflow I think. You might find [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4tuhg7b50I) informative since it kind of covers the basics of react-virtualized. After that I would suggest browsing [the documentation](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/tree/master/docs).

Once you have a foundation then more specific questions could be directed here or to the [react-virtualized Slack channel](https://react-virtualized.now.sh/).